# Rollup is not found in LIBL type *N

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run the following SQL:

```
SELECT ITEM , HOUSE , LOC , LBHNO , SUM ( QTY )
FROM LIBRARY. TABLE1
GROUP BY ROLLUP ( ITEM , HOUSE , LOC , LBHNO ) ;
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR [42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - ROLLUP in *LIBL type *N not found.

I am using IBM i Access for Windows, Version 7 Release 1 Service level SI53584

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of IBM i Access doesn't matter.  You can use a newer version of i Access with server on an older release...or vice versa.

You need to see what OS version your server is actually running.

From a command line:

- DSPSFWRSC, F11-Display Libraries/Releases
- DSPPTF
- GO LICPGM, option 10 - Display Installed LICPGM

Using the System i Navigator component of IBM i Access for Windows...
Right-click on the system and select properties.

ROLLUP and CUBE were added at IBM i version 6.1

Comment: From the error message it looks like it's pre-6.1: `[DB2 for i5/OS]`